# How to do slug URL like WordPress?

Tags: url, url-rewriting

We have many blog articles on our webserver and the files which is exists exactly. For example: `https://domain/blog/123.php`. We import all files into database and the front end just retrieve the content (title,content,etc.) from table.

I use a dynamic page to show all articles content. But for url , it will be generated like this:

```
https://domain/blog/detail.php?q=123.php
https://domain/blog/detail.php?q=456.php
```

It will affect seo ranking, so how can we keep the same url like WordPress?

```
https://domain/blog/123.php
https://domain/blog/456.php
https://domain/blog/789.php
```

I am using apache so .htaccess is available. I am trying to rewrite the url.

```
RewriteRule    ^blog/123.php$     /blog/detail.php?q=123.php [L]
```

but it is not meet our requirement. I don't want show any url like `/blog/detail.php?q=123.php`. I just want to keep the slug url.

Answer (score -1):

If you use apache/nginx for web server check [htaccess](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) configuration.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547015/htaccess-rewrite-slug-to-seo-url) is similar to your question.