# How to get arguments from route PHP

Tags: php, rest

So I have a doubt, and I'am not really sure how to solve it.

I'am trying to make a rest API with PHP, no framework, nothing, so first of all I thought of making
The functions: get, show,create, update, delete.

Like that I will be able to call the function
needed, the first parameter will be the url where is going to make the petition and the second one will be a function, like this, for example:

```
function get($url,$func){
}
```

I did my research and I know from where to start initially,
However, my problem starts when I want to get the parameter of the route,
Like for example if I use a framework, I will be like this:

```
SHOW
$app->post("/show/{id}","show_f");
```

in the above example the route will be "show" and the "id" will be the argument.
However, my problem is how can I get the argument (id) of the route

Do I need to convert to an array the $url value? (like this: `explode('/', $url);`),

so like that when I receive the initial value will be a string, however, when I split it, I will get an array of the route and the argument.
Does it sound reasonable, or do I complicate myself?

Comment: You can have a look at `.htaccess`, e.g. an example here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18547036/13467725

The first `(.*)` will convert to `$1` and you can use `$_GET` to get the value in your PHP script

Comment: If you don’t want to use a framework, that’s fine, but that doesn’t mean you can’t peak at how they do it. Here’s a simple single class router with RegEx patterns: https://github.com/bramus/router

Comment: @GlennM I see, looks like a good option, i will try it, Thanks!!

Comment: @ChrisHaas I would love to use frameworks, however in this project I prefer to learn by myself all the coding behind routing, i will check the link that you have sended to me, Thanks too!

Comment: As you advance, you learn not to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @haruk1515, I applaud you for doing that!

Comment: @RápliAndrás I agree with you totally, however, this project is oriented to learn, 
a challenge to myself, regards